# Excel VBA Assigning Printer Port

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I was wondering if anyone else has had any issues with coding in a printer on a specific USB port in VBA. I have a USB printer in my VBA code "Zebra Z1 on Ne06:" I am changing from a default printer to the USB printer to print a barcode label and then changing back to the default printer but I have had issues where the port has changed to Ne00:   Does anyone know how can this be resolved in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do quite a bit of digging, because VBA is not mainstream.  Find some code that can look up installed devices.  I think you will have to use some windows API code can dig through the windows registry.  Your best approach will be to find code samples written for classic Visual Basic, and adapt it to your project.  (I did VB development professionally for several years, with intermittent use of VBA.)